# jquery live hover not working

Tags: jquery

I ran into some dropdown flickering issue on IE due to mouseover and mouseout , so i changed the code
to hover and live as the data is dynamic from ajax.

But the following code is not working , i got the latest jquery also.

The following code is getting executed without error but not working

```
$('.cs-rec').live("hover",
        function() {       
        $(this).find('.cs-title').css('text-decoration','underline');
        },
        function() {
         $(this).find('.cs-title').css('text-decoration','none');
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need IE6 support, go with @patrick's solution absolutely.

If you *do* have to support it: There's no 2 method overload for [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) you need to split up like this:

```
$('.cs-rec').live("mouseenter", function() {       
  $(this).find('.cs-title').css('text-decoration','underline');
}).live("mouseleave", function() {
  $(this).find('.cs-title').css('text-decoration','none');
});
```

Or, (though it's not in the docs yet) in jQuery 1.4.3+ can take a map, like this:

```
$('.cs-rec').live({
  mouseenter: function() {       
    $(this).find('.cs-title').css('text-decoration','underline');
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    $(this).find('.cs-title').css('text-decoration','none');
  }
});
```

Comment: @nick , the above code is not working , moreover its making the menu on the following page flickers , the above code will go live later , but the drops downs like art styles , subjects flickers on IE if have the above code http://locwww.art.com/products/p12838878-sa-i2055985/vincent%20van%20gogh-almond%20branches%20in%20bloom,%20san%20remy,%20c.1890.htm?sorig=cat&sorigid=0&dimvals=23944&ui=29ccdb60b8304c9c8de9008b6c546003

Comment: @gov - It flickers because it maps to `mouseover` and `mouseout` which fire even when entering children...is CSS not an option here?  Or the option to bind directly so you can *actually* use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`?

Comment: @gov - no not inline - I mean not `.live()`, bind directly to the elements, e.g. `$('.cs-rec').hover(...)`.

Comment: @nick , the data as a apart of ajax call, so i cannot use regular bind.

Comment: @nick if you have time can you please explain in detail why IE flickers for these mouseover events.

Comment: @gov - because it's alternating between styles as you move in/out of children.  Also you *can* use a regular bind, jut do it when the AJAX call completes :)

Comment: wow , this is good idea , ajax call completes binding. Nick you rocks.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you don't use CSS for this? IE6 won't work, but most others will.

```
.cs-red .cs-title {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.cs-red:hover .cs-title {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

**EDIT:** Looking at your site, if it is the navigation area that you're talking about, you could adjust the markup so that you have an `<a>` inside each `<li>` that is expanded to the full width and height of the `<li>`.

This way, IE6 could be supported (placing the `:hover` on the `<a>`).

Answer (score 1):

Binding to hover is possible, but tricky:

> As of jQuery 1.4.1 the hover event can
>   be specified (mapping to mouseenter
>   and mouseleave, which, in turn, are
>   mapped to mouseover and mouseout).

You have to use a single method and then switch the behavior based on the event type (code example taken from jQuery docs as well):

```
$('.hoverme').live('hover', function(event) {
    if (event.type == 'mouseenter') {
        // do something on mouseover
    } else {
        // do something on mouseout
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.edit_hover').live('hover', function(event) {
  if (event.type == 'mouseenter') {
    // first function here
  } else {
    // second function here
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**this is true...**

```
$("#your_div_id").live('mouseover',function(){

    $(this).find(".child_div").css('background-color','#111111');

}).live('mouseout',function(){

     $(this).find(".child_div").css('background-color','#757575');
});
```